# Images not properly sent in email

Tags: html, email, image

I have created an email template, I use PHP to send the email, but the problem is that images that I have included inside the email template are not being displayed properly.  It's showing the cross symbol.  In Outlook, they mention "click here to download the image" - but nothing happens when I click.

What is the solution for this? How can I send the email along with the image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are best off not sending images in the email itself, but rather linking to them on the web. So, in your email, you have:

```
<img src="http://www.example.org/picture.jpg" alt="My Picture">
```

Comment: Best put the whole HTML on the web really; HTML in mail has so many limitations and gotchas it's usually easier just to send a link!